# "No resource found that matches the given name" error even though the names match

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I'm building a simple todo list app.  I'm trying to organise my layout by positioning them relative to one another.  I do that by calling XML attributes like `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/to_do_btn"` but however I'm getting a `No Resource Found That Matches The Given Name` error.  I basically tried every solution on Stackoverflow but nothing helped.  This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapp.onur.todo.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/to_do_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/to_do_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to_do_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Something To Do"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/to_do_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/to_do_btn"
        android:layout_below="@id/to_do_list"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/to_do_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add item"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is an example of the error: `Error:(15, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/to_do_btn').`

I have no idea what's going on.  If it helps, here are my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change

```
android:layout_above="@id/to_do_btn"
```

to

```
android:layout_above="@+id/to_do_btn"
```

**OR** order your layout like this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/to_do_btn"
        ...
        />

<ListView
        ...
        android:layout_above="@id/to_do_btn"
        >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 12):

Phan Van Linh's answer is correct, but here's *why* it's correct.

When you write `@+id/foo`, you're saying "use the id `foo`, and create it if it doesn't exist". When you write `@id/foo`, you're saying "use the id `foo`". If that id doesn't exist, this is an error (just like referencing a Java variable you haven't declared).

The reason it "works" if you put your layouts in the opposite order is that now your `<Button android:id="@+id/foo">` tag comes first, so when the file is being processed, the id `foo` is created before `<ListView android:layout_above="@id/foo">` is processed.

In fact, if you swap the two views, build your project, and then swap them back to the original order, you'll find that it *still* works. This is because the generated `R.java` file is built incrementally, so the id `foo` sticks around from the last build.

But if you do a clean rebuild of your project, the problem will come back (because R.java is destroyed and regenerated).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I tried to run

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Thanks for your friendship"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/text4"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Signed: Kingsley"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
```

The solution was to simply reorder the text views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've upvoted you out of appreciation. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?